# Disabling/enabled textbox in GridViewRow

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a checkbox and a textbox in a GridView (for every row), and I'd like to be able to write some javascript that would enable and disable the textbox depending on the state of the checkbox (checked or unchecked). I guess I'd have to give JS the row index somehow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your replies, I have worked around this issue by just doing a postback - not the best method but due to time constraints it was the logical choice

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to use jquery then this can be very easily accomplished as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.grid tr').each(function() {
      var r = $(this);
      var c = r.find('.check');
      var t = r.find('.text');
      var f = function(c1, t1) { return function() {
            if (c1.attr('checked')) {
               t1.removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {
               t1.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
         };
      };
      c.click(f(c, t)); // attach click event handler
      f(c, t); // set initial state
   });
});
```

Above script is assuming that the gridview table is decorated with `grid` css class and each textbox and checkbox  are decorated with `check` and `text` css class respectively.

Comment: The only thing I have to add this is to disable view state validation on the asp.net page. Because you are modifying the state of controls in the page, view state validation is going to throw errors. Such errors are intermittent and hard to debug, but they are there. Disabling view state validation prevents this and gives JavaScript a chance to modify html controls at the client side, while forcing the server side to not throw a fuss about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is absolutely possible. 
To implement this you need to do the following:

1. Write a generic JavaScript function to handle the enabling/disabling of a Text-Box based on the state of the Check-Box; 
   Example :-

   `function ManageControlEnabling(sourceCheckBoxId, affectingControlId)

   {

   var sourceCheckBox = document.getElementById(sourceCheckBoxId);

   var affectingControl = document.getElementById(affectingControlId);

   var shouldEnable = false;`

   if (sourceCheckBox && affectingControl)
   {
       shouldEnable = sourceCheckBox.checked;

   ```
   if(shouldEnable)
       affectingControl.disabled = false;
   else
       affectingControl.disabled = true;
   ```

   }
   }
2. Handle the Row-Data-Bound event of the Grid-View. Implement a similar functionality in your .Net code, to handle the enabling/disabling of the text-box (for each row) based on the state of the check-box. And also add the JavaScript function to the check-box; 
   Example :-

   ```
   CheckBox checkSource;
   TextBox textAffecting;


   checkSource = e.Row.FindControl("cbSource") as CheckBox;
   textAffecting = e.Row.FindControl("tbAffecting") as TextBox;


   if(checkSource != null)
   {
       textAffecting.Enabled = checkSource.Checked;
   }


   checkSource.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ManageControlEnabling('" + checkSource.ClientID + "', '" + textAffecting.ClientID + "', true);");
   ```

---

Please see if this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) sadly it doesn't work - the rowdatabound part works (it adds the attributes, and the textbox is disabled/enabled depending on the checkbox state), but it never enables the textbox when I click the checkbox - even if I take out all the if's and just have it enable the textbox.